# Android Code=400 "Bad Request" on POST attempt

Tags: android, kotlin, post, retrofit, retrofit2

i bumped on some problem with my POST method an error=400 which is "bad request".

I simplified my code as much as it's possible just to make it work, but 400 still appears. Am I missing something? Is the problem on my side or server by any chance ?

Code:

FormApiInterface.kt

```
interface FormApiInterface {
    @POST("/forms/filledForm")
    fun sendTrashForm(@Body filledForm: TempFilledForm): Call<TempFilledForm>
}
```

MenuActivity.kt

```
class MenuActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var apiInterface : FormApiInterface

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(activity_main)

        val apiClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL_POST)
            .client(apiClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

        apiInterface = retrofit.create(FormApiInterface::class.java)
    }

    fun sendTrash() {
        val tempFilledForm = TempFilledForm(
            userLogin = "filledForm?.userLogin",
            formId = "filledForm?.userLogin",
            formVersion = "filledForm?.formVersion",
            formStatus = "filledForm?.formStatus",
            form = "filledForm?.formFieldsData")

        val call: Call<TempFilledForm> = apiInterface.sendTrashForm(tempFilledForm)

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<TempFilledForm> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<TempFilledForm>?, t: Throwable?) {
                Log.v("retrofit", "call failed")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<TempFilledForm>?, response: Response<TempFilledForm>?) {
                Log.v("retrofit", response.toString())
            }
        })
    }
```

Im calling sendTrash() inside some onClick in my Activity and the response is like

```
V/retrofit: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=, url=http:--------(covered it)}
```

None of "similar" questions helped. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: have you added the interceptors it will log the detailed error log received from the api response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Shahriyar Aghajani pointed out. Try removing "/" from your service.

```
interface FormApiInterface {
    @POST("forms/filledForm")
    fun sendTrashForm(@Body filledForm: TempFilledForm): Call<ResponseObject>
}
```

And moreover, Is your server sending back same object as response back?

Ideally response would be different from your input body object!

```
@Body filledForm: TempFilledForm
```

And response object from backend `Call<ResponseObject>`

If you have configured end point in build.gradle, Make sure your end point ends with "/"

```
buildTypes {

  debug {
    buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"http://191.111.3.170:8000/sample/"'
  }

}
```

Comment: It was different response object indeed.I put there my body object by accident and didn't notice it. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

delete "/" from start of your end point:

```
interface FormApiInterface {
    @POST("forms/filledForm")
    fun sendTrashForm(@Body filledForm: TempFilledForm): Call<TempFilledForm>
}
```

and add "/" to end of your base url

Comment: @Alky check your response model, it is exactly like your sendig body? (TempFilledForm)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find out what is the reason of "bad request" by adding some logs to onResponse method:

```
Log.d("TEST", " errorBody: ${response.errorBody()?.string()}")
```

Maybe you are sending wrong parameters.

If you try to initialize `tempFilledForm` variable using another model, use `$` operator for string interpolation, and use curly braces for expressions:

```
val tempFilledForm = TempFilledForm(
        userLogin = "${filledForm?.userLogin}",
        formId = "${filledForm?.userLogin}",
        formVersion = "${filledForm?.formVersion}",
        formStatus = "${filledForm?.formStatus}",
        form = "${filledForm?.formFieldsData}")
```